# How to change the order of fields in comment form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I currently use Iconic One Theme (WordPress).
Strangely, email field appears first in comment form.
[image]

I tried to change the order of the fields between "author" and "email" by referring to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form, but I couldn't.

How can I switch the order of email and author fields in wordpress comment system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields =  array(

  'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',
);
```

This should change it like you said if doesn't work you might have the theme that you are using overriding it somewhere or you can try deleting the field and adding your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use following filter to change order of fields-

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 't5_move_textarea' );
add_action( 'comment_form_top', 't5_move_textarea' );

function t5_move_textarea( $input = array () )
{
    static $textarea = '';

    if ( 'comment_form_defaults' === current_filter() )
    {
        // Copy the field to our internal variable …
        $textarea = $input['comment_field'];
        // … and remove it from the defaults array.
        $input['comment_field'] = '';
        return $input;
    }

    print apply_filters( 'comment_form_field_comment', $textarea );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try looking at different forums ?

try looking at this:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50593/how-to-rearrange-fields-in-comment-form

Comment: Thanks for your answer.